# In Ionic 4 with angular 8..... Broadcaster is not working. I am not able to get data from native to typescript file

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native

In Ionic 4 with angular 8..... Broadcaster is not working. I am not able to get data from native to typescript file.

So can anyone help me in this?

reference link https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/broadcaster/

app.component.ts

```
import { Broadcaster } from '@ionic-native/broadcaster/ngx';

constructor(private broadcaster: Broadcaster) { }

...

// Listen to events from Native
this.broadcaster.addEventListener('TEST.EVENT').subscribe((event) => console.log(event));
```

Android code

```
void sendJSMessage() {
        final Intent intent = new Intent("TEST.EVENT");

        final Bundle child = new Bundle();
        child.putString( "name", "joker");

        final Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString( "data", "test");
        b.putBoolean( "valid", true );
        b.putBundle( "child", child );

        intent.putExtras( b);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcastSync(intent);
    }
```

Comment: what is error console ?

Comment: error is not showing in console

Comment: please help me because in latest ionic native is not working with angular 8 but older version is working with old angular......i need help....can you help me in this?